# Angular values do not reflect in scope until view changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my HTML code :

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron" id="welcomehead">

            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Welcome {{username }}, your Season total is {{total }}</h2>  

            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 id="slogan" >5 teams; 1 Goal</h3><br>
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1508887997/ymkit_ww8np1.jpg">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1508888352/indkit_zop1gx.jpg">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1508887290/chad2kit_fa3lrh.jpg">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1508887718/fbg2kit_lzndap.jpg">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1508888206/vgc_kit_hvpdz4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is the javascript code for the html code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('TNF.welcome', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/welcome',{
    templateUrl:'welcome/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
 });
}])

.controller('WelcomeCtrl',['$scope','$firebaseAuth','CommonProp','$location','DatabaseService',
     function($scope,$firebaseAuth, CommonProp,$location, databaseService){


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    databaseService.users.child(user.uid).once('value', function(usersSnapshot){
    var users = usersSnapshot.val();
    var total = users.total;
   $scope.username = user.email; 
   $scope.total = total;

  }, function(err) {
       console.log(err);
        $scope.total = 0;
    });
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    $location.path('/home');
  }
});





$scope.logout = function(){
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
  $location.path('/home');
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});
};
```

MY Issue

My issue is that the `{{username}}` and `{{total}}` values, which are results of the firebase query do not show in the view once the page loads. However, the values show up once I leave the page and then return to the view. Does this mean that the HTML code loads faster than the firebase query can be resolved? If so, is there a way to make the page only load AFTER the firebase query is resolved?

Comment: Are you missing to change the path to '/welcome' ?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure hey I accidentally left it out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to let angular know to run an update.

```
$scope.username = user.email; 
$scope.total = total;
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: hey @sajeetharan if you dont mind my asking, what exactly does $scope.$apply(); do? how would this make the firebase query run faster or make the html code only be injected after the the firebase query returns with the relevant data?

Comment: first of all it does not have anything to do with firebase or to make the query run faster. in angularjs it just let angular know that value has been updated. btw did it work for u

Comment: i think it did work because the issue is no longer there. I will let you know if it it pops up after a refresh again. Thanks and God bless

Comment: @DejiJames please mark as answer and upvote if this helped